# Start a deamon through cronjob in python

Tags: python, django

I am trying to call a deamon process through cronjob, which can be called using

```
root@ip:/home/web/path_to_directory# python api/api_daemon.py start
```

I have tried the following approaches

```
 import os
    os.system("/usr/bin/python /home/web/path_to_directory/api/api_daemon.py start")


import os
os.system("python /home/web/path_to_directory/api/api_daemon.py start")

import os
os.system("python api/api_daemon.py start")#works on shell and when triggered manually
```

**Edit 1**
Basically, I am using a cron job to check if the process is running or not, if process is not running, then only process will get called.

```
def process_check():
      process_list = ['api_daemon.py']
      for process in process_list:
             processname =  'python api/'+process+' start'
             #print processname
             tmp = os.popen("ps -Af").read()
             proccount = tmp.count(processname)
             message1 =  'processes running of %s' % (processname)
             print proccount
             #proccount = -2
             if not proccount > 0 :
                   logging.info('status file stopped')
                   send_msg(process)  # to notify process has been restarted
                   run_process()
def run_process():
    import os
    os.system("chdir /home/web/path_to_directory && python api/api_daemon.py start")
```

Through cronjob `process_check()` is being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `api_daemon.py` scrpt depends on some module from `/home/web/path_to_directory`, you must add that directory to path or chdir to that directory first.

That being said, you can try to invoke command:

```
chdir /home/web/path_to_directory && python api/api_daemon.py start
```

In your crontab file. That will first go to directory of your project, then start your `api_daemon`.

Comment: I have tried using absolute path as well (refer 2nd approach)

Comment: For python, it does matter from what directory script is invoked. So you must explicitly chdir to particular directory for script to work.